# How can I update all images with the same src URL

Tags: jquery

I have a simple question. Is it possible to update all images on a website which have the same image-url?

For example I have the URL 'http://www.example.com/mynewimage_new.png'

Now I want to set all images on the site that have the image-url "http://www.example.com/mynewimage_old.png" to the new url.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  As with any jQuery operation it mainly comes down to your selector and your operation on the matched elements.  In this case the selector is all `img` elements with a given `src` value:

```
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/mynewimage_old.png"]')
```

And the operation is to set a new `src` value:

```
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/mynewimage_old.png"]').prop('src', 'http://www.example.com/mynewimage_old.png');
```